# Ambient filter / interceptors for domain classes in Gorm / Grails?

Tags: logging, grails, dns, grails-orm, interceptor

I just integrated a logging concept for my Grails system and used the filter mechanism to log access to my controllers and actions. The good thing is that I can define one filter for all controller and actions.

With domain classes I do only know the interceptor concept where I have to write an interceptor for every individual domain class. Is there a concept similar to filters for domain classes where I can define an interceptor for ALL domain classes?

Many thanks in advance,
Joerg.

UPDATE 1:
Thank you for the tip on the Audit Logging Plugin by Stefan. The Audit Logging Plugin looks like the easiest alternative but produces too many rows/logs for my taste and does not use the grails/log4j logging system.

Currently, my requirements are:

1. Log the insert/update/delete for all domain classes (in order to log only the incidents, not every change to every field/column)
2. Log to the Grails logging system (log4j) in order to log to stdout, individual database tables, or email (The level might be, e.g., INFO or TRACE)
3. Log to a special domain class (db table) in order to build a log visualization / management system on top of it (via Grails controller & actions). Here it would be great to configure if the logs are in the same or another database/grails-app (in order to split the log management system later on).

As far as I know a simple "change" logging can be done via:

1. Individual log statements in domain classes (requires insert/update/delete events in every domain class)
2. Define a "Log" Superclass which inherits the insert/update/delete events (makes it hard to make indivudal insert/update/delete events in special domain classes)
3. Define a Filter for all controllers but only save/update/delete actions (problem: does not log changes to domain classes without an controller or if multiple domain classes are touched in one action)

Hope this helps other. Nevertheless, Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe http://www.grails.org/plugin/audit-logging is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. The Audit Logging Plugin is capable of logging the domain classes to a database table. However it seems that it is not very easy to configure. I have not found a way to configure the database, table columns or the level of logging. For example, the plugin logs every change to every field of a domain class, which makes it possible to use it as a versioning system (you can rollback every change). However, I only need logging of the change itself (insert, update, delete) and would like to use the configured log4j logging (i.e. my own appenders to databases, files or email).

Comment: Another option would be overriding the 'eventTriggeringInterceptor' in resources.groovy. By default this bean uses ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor that delegates to the onXXX methods in each of the domain classes. By using some custom class for eventTriggeringInterceptor you can handle events on a global level and not domain class specific.

Comment: amending yesterday's comment: take a look at http://www.grails.org/plugin/falcone-util. It also provides a event mechanism for hibernate events.